# Is it possible(if yes, what is the best way) to build electron app having node-hid as a dependency on linux using docker for windows 32bit?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Using docker image `electronuserland/builder:wine` trying to build:

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-builder --win --ia32`

outputs:

```
  • loaded configuration  file=/project/electron-builder.yml
  • writing effective config  file=build/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=node-hid@2.1.1, sqlite3@4.2.0, usb-detection@4.10.0 platform=win32 arch=ia32
  • install prebuilt binary  name=usb-detection version=4.10.0 platform=win32 arch=ia32
  • install prebuilt binary  name=node-hid version=2.1.1 platform=win32 arch=ia32
  ⨯ cannot build native dependency  reason=prebuild-install failed with error and build from sources not possible because platform or arch not compatible
                                    cause=exit status 1
                                    errorOut=prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 5.3.6
    prebuild-install WARN install prebuilt binaries enforced with --force!
    prebuild-install WARN install prebuilt binaries may be out of date!
    prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /root/.npm/_prebuilds/c5dfd1-node-hid-v2.1.1-electron-v76-win32-ia32.tar.gz
    prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/releases/download/v2.1.1/node-hid-v2.1.1-electron-v76-win32-ia32.tar.gz
    prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/releases/download/v2.1.1/node-hid-v2.1.1-electron-v76-win32-ia32.tar.gz
    prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=8.1.1 runtime=electron arch=ia32 libc= platform=win32)
    
                                    command=/usr/local/bin/node /project/node_modules/prebuild-install/bin.js --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --target=8.1.1 --runtime=electron --verbose --force
                                    workingDir=/project/node_modules/node-hid
```

What am I missing? Or is it actually required in this case to build app on windows machine?